# Detecting .png alpha channel in Windows/D3D

Tags: windows, png, direct3d, alpha

I'm loading a texture from .png using D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(). How can my program know if the image file contains an alpha channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't too hard to do by simply examining the file.

A PNG file consists of:

- A file header
- One or more 'chunks'

The file header is always 8 bytes and should be skipped over.

Each chunk begins with 4 bytes indicating its length, and 4 bytes indicating its type. The first chunk should always be 13 bytes and have the type `IHDR`. This contains the information about the image.

The tenth byte in the header contains the exact information you're looking for. It will be equal to `6` if the PNG file is RGBA.

More information can be found [here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IHDR).

Answer (score 1):

Call `IDirect3DTexture9::GetSurfaceLevel` and then call `IDirect3DSurface9::GetDesc`. The [D3DSURFACE_DESC.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172558.aspx) member will tell you.